# Stop setTimeout loop, activated after click on button

Tags: javascript

I want to rotate list of urls from textarea in iframe. This is  what my code looks like:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("addurls").onclick = function () {
    var urls = $('#allurls').val().split('\n');
    var index = 0;
    var el = document.getElementById("indexer");
    setTimeout(function rotate() {
      if (index === urls.length) {
        index = 0;
      }
      el.src = urls[index];
      index++;
      setTimeout(rotate, 1000);
    }, 0);
  };
</script>
```

But how can I stop this loop after last url opened in iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what you want (you can remove the console stmt after testing),

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("addurls").onclick = function () {
    var allurls  = document.getElementById("allurls"); //$('#allurls').val().split('\n');
    var urls  = allurls.value.split('\n');
    var el    = document.getElementById("indexer");
    var index = 0;

    timer = setTimeout(function rotate() {

      if (index === urls.length) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        return true;
      }

      el.src = urls[index];
      console.log("TEST: ", index);
      index++;

      timer = setTimeout(rotate, 2000);
    }, 0);
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the timeout to a variable and then call `clearTimeout` on it.

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

From https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp